# HTML Detail tag height adjustment based on open/close attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have [details](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp) tag which **css height** i want to adjust through javascript/jquery. if the details tag has open attribute then height will be 200 else it will be 40 but i am unable to do this.

```
 $jq("#ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel").click(function(){

           console.log("change occur");
            if($jq("#ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel").attr("open")){
                console.log("open found");
                $jq("#ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel").css("height","");
                $jq("#ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel").css("height","200px");
            }else{
                console.log("open found");
                $jq("#ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel").css("height","");
                $jq("#ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel").css("height","40px");
            }
        });
```

while my details html is

```
<details class="bottom-panel" id="ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel" style="position: fixed;
        bottom: 80px;
        right: 0px;
        background: rgb(244, 238, 238);
        padding-left:5px;
        color: rgb(180, 17, 17);
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 40px;
        ">
    <div id="ProjectQuestionAnswer">
    </div>
</details>
```

Comment: check this out https://jsfiddle.net/5evfa9k1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I don't have any misunderstanding of your question.
You can change the height by using the css

HTML:

```
<details class="bottom-panel" id="ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel">
    <div id="ProjectQuestionAnswer">
    <p>Answer Here.</p>
    <p>Answer Here.</p>
    <p>Answer Here.</p>
    </div>
</details>
```

CSS:

```
details[open]{
  height: 200px;
}

details{
  height: 40px;
}
```

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xdbz0kgm/).

Also, be careful that `details` tag is not supported at IE and Edge.
http://caniuse.com/#search=details

Comment: Of course yes. Then "details[open]" becomes "details[open]#yourid" and "details" becomes "details#yourid". Also, this article may help you https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/

Comment: Love you my boy. Welcome to stackoverflow with your first voted and accepted answer.! thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct Jquery and HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<details class="bottom-panel" id="ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel" style="position: fixed;
        bottom: 80px;
        right: 0px;
        background: rgb(244, 238, 238);
        padding-left:5px;
        color: rgb(180, 17, 17);
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 40px;
        ">
    <div id="ProjectQuestionAnswer">
    </div>
</details>
  <script>
    $("#ProjectQuestionAnswerBottomPanel").click(function(){

           console.log("change occur");
            if(typeof $(this).attr("open") !== 'undefined'){
                console.log("open found");
                $(this).css("height","");
                $(this).css("height","200px");
            }else{
                console.log("open Not found");
                $(this).css("height","");
                $(this).css("height","40px");
            }
        });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ceperecoju/edit?html,console,output)